# SSRS email subscription with custom file name on the attachment

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs

I would like to set up an SSRS email subscription that attaches the report in PDF format to the email with a custom file name that changes daily.  I was hopeful that I could to this via a data-driven subscription, but that does not seem possible.  Does anyone have a handy work-around for this limitation?

**UPDATE**: @swasheck provided a decent work-around, and one that we currently use.  But I am hoping to remove the step of saving to a file-share.

Comment: How are you creating the PDF? SSIS expressions might be an option for you, but let's hear about how the PDF originates.

Comment: Not very exciting - just by rending the report as PDF as defined in the subscription.

Answer (score 1):

This is the first way I could think of to make this happen:

1. Create a data-driven subscription for the report
2. Specify `Windows File Share` as the delivery method (this would imply that you had a file share location available)
3. Connect to a data source
4. Write a query to generate the name
5. Specify that name as the report name in the location of your file share
6. Have a process by which the end-users are emailed this report - perhaps a SQL Agent job?

As a matter of personal exploration, I wonder if it'd be possible to modify the SQL Agent job that the subscription creates such that you could add a step to send the file via email.

Comment: Good work around - and actually what we currently do.  :)